# Creating an autoresizing printout

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing

My application needs to print something. The layout should be somewhat dynamic (sometimes particular fields may contain more data, which could require them being word-wrapped or some such), but the printout should never be more than a single page. If there's too much data, I want to reduce the font size slightly and try again, and repeat that until everything fits on a single page (there will never be *so* many data that the font will be unreadably small).

I need to print both text and images on the same page.

The layout should look something like the following:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +------+                                               +-------+ |
| | seal |                   text field 1                | photo | |
| |      |                   text field 2                |       | |
| +------+                                               +-------+ |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------- |
|  text header 1:                 text data                        |
|  text header 2:                 longer text data                 |
|  text header 3 with long title: very long text data which does   |
|                                 not fit on a single line         |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------- |
|  text header 4:                 text data                        |
.                                                                  .
.     (...)                          (...)                         .
.                                                                  .
|                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The data for `text field 1` is slightly variable, but not to the extent that it matters. The data for `text field 2` can be fairly short, but can be extremely long too, and should fit between the two image elements, wordwrapping if necessary. Both fields should be (approximately) centered, vertically, between the two images.

The data fields on the rest of the page is grouped with vertical lines in between, but all data fields should start at the same offset from the left of the page, which is defined by the length of the longest header.

I've managed this partially using a freestanding `NSView` (freestanding, as in, not part of a window) in my XIB file. I've created `NSTextField` elemnts to hold the headers and the data. The alignment requirements are defined as constraints on the `NSTextField` elements, and if everything fits (i.e., no word wrapping is required, and the font size doesn't need to be reduced), it looks vaguely like the way it should.

However, there are a few issues remaining:

- I can't figure out how to make an `NSTextField` wrap its text but stay as small, vertically, as needed to fit everything. It looks like I either need to make it more than one line high (which would result in unwanted empty space between lines), or the word wrap will obscure the second line.
- The printing API wants me to pass an `NSView` before I know what the printable area on the page will be. As such, I don't see an option for me to resize the `NSView` so it fits optimally on the page. Currently, that results in a page which has overly large side margins or overly large top/bottom margins, depending on the printer used and its settings.

Am I going about this the right way? If so, how should I fix the above two issues? If not, what should I be doing instead?

I did have a look at the Core Printing API, but that seems a bit too low level.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NSTextField will wrap and will be just high enough if you set Behaviour to None or Selectable.

To resize the print view, you create a subclass of NSView and implement knowsPageRange: and rectForPage:. In knowsPageRange: you calculate the number of pages (1) and return YES. In rectForPage: you set height and width constraints so the view will be the same size as the page, call [self layoutSubtreeIfNeeded] and return self.bounds. [[NSPrintOperation currentOperation] printInfo] will give you the printinfo.

Comment: Could you provide a basic example on how I can assign height and width constraints based on a given page size? I've been trying, but can't figure it out (partially because I've never done programmatical constraints before)

Comment: `[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
        toItem:nil
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
       multiplier:1.0
         constant:canvasSize.width]];` self is the view.